# Testing my sorting function

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I'm trying to sort an array of numbers using Selectionsort and generics and I'm feeling lost. I have an Interface with public T[] sort and public void swap. What do I have to fix to return a sorted array of integers?

My code is:

```
package sorting;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Selectionsort<T extends Comparable<T>> implements
    ISelectionsort<T> {

private T[] array;

@Override
public T[] sort(T[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int k = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if ((array[j].compareTo(array[k]) == -1))
                k = j;
        }
        if (k != i)
            swap(array, i, k);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void swap(T[] array, int i, int j) {
    T tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Selectionsort<Integer> ss = new Selectionsort<Integer>();
    Integer[] array = { 4, 2, 9, 8 };

    System.out.println(ss.sort(array));
}
}
```

Comment: you do not need to return anything, you swap elements in original array, thus original array is sorted when Selectionsort#sort completes

Comment: Why does your `sort` returns a `null` and not a sorted array? Why does it have to return something when it actually sorts the array in-place?

Comment: Variables are pointers to a part of memory. If you use your method, you are already sorting the content of your variable. Your `System.out` will print 'null' into your console, because all you do in your method is change the position of the variable values. You will have to go through your array and extract your values 1 by 1 with a `for` loop.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX: or simply use `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, but for that he will have to return the array. I'm speaking that if you already sort your variable in the method it has no sense to return the variable. Just have to do `ss.sort(array); for(...) {System.out.println("Position " + i + ": " + array[i])};`

Comment: Yeah, I used System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); and I'm able to return my array (however it didn't sort correctly).

However I'm not able to use the debug mode. I put a breakpoint on the T[] sort line and it simply executes instead of going in debug mode. What do?

Comment: Why you use your swap method out of the loop? I'm not sure, just I think that you have the problem there. I added this to favourites. If when I go back home it's not answered, I will try to execute the code , check what is wrong and try to solve it.

Comment: My task was to write the body of the Selectionsort method and the swap method. The rest was already given and I have to adapt to it. Thanks!

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX: you contradict yourself. You're saying first that he has to return the array to be able to print it, and then you're saying that the array is sorted in place so there's no need to return anything. I agree that noting should be returned. I'm just saying that instead of using a loop to print the array, he just needs to use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))`

Comment: I get an error if I return nothing in the sort method.

"This method must return a result of type T[]"
"implements sorting.ISelectionsort<T>.sort" (ISelectionsort is my interface)

Comment: @Pulz put it as `public void`.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not contradicting myself O.o I just said that if he **WANTS** to print the array returned, you have to add it at the return of the method instead to return `null`. Also, said that If the variable it's pointing at a part of memory, you **DON'T NEED** to return anything. The method is already sorting the variable content. You will just need to go through that variable and get value by value all the array values already sorted. I don't know if it is already clear :S probably I missed to clarify something.

Comment: Already tried it before. "void[] is an invalid type" "Return type for the method is missing."

Comment: @Pulz `public void sort(params)`

Comment: Here's a pastebin for anyone interested: http://pastebin.com/muJ0fz6A

Comment: @Pulz Thanks. In around 2-3 hours I will go back home and will try your method and let's see if we can solve this, if it's not solved in that time. Sorry, but I can't be more faster.

Comment: No problem dude, thanks for using your free time.

Comment: Okay, it works fine now. I forgot to set the j-for on j = i + 1. Now it sorts correctly

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

start `j` from `k`:

```
for (int j = k; j < array.length; j++) {
```

return the same arary:

```
return array;
```

and print like :

```
    ss.sort(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```